# Reading motion vectors of every 60th frame in video file

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I have the following code which reads a video files and extracts motion vectors from each frame and outputs them to stdout:

```c
#include <libavutil/motion_vector.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>

static AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx = NULL;
static AVCodecContext *video_dec_ctx = NULL;
static AVStream *video_stream = NULL;
static const char *src_filename = NULL;

static int video_stream_idx = -1;
static AVFrame *frame = NULL;
static int video_frame_count = 0;

static int decode_packet(const AVPacket *pkt)
{
    //fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", video_dec_ctx->width);
    int ret = avcodec_send_packet(video_dec_ctx, pkt);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while sending a packet to the decoder: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
        return ret;
    }

    while (ret >= 0)  {
        ret = avcodec_receive_frame(video_dec_ctx, frame);
        if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
            break;
        } else if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error while receiving a frame from the decoder: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
            return ret;
        }

        if (ret >= 0) {
            int i;
            AVFrameSideData *sd;

            video_frame_count++;
            sd = av_frame_get_side_data(frame, AV_FRAME_DATA_MOTION_VECTORS);
            if (sd) {
                const AVMotionVector *mvs = (const AVMotionVector *)sd->data;
                for (i = 0; i < sd->size / sizeof(*mvs); i++) {
                    const AVMotionVector *mv = &mvs[i];
                    printf("%d,%4d,%4d,%4d\n",
                        video_frame_count,
                        abs(mv->src_x - mv->dst_x),
                        abs(mv->src_y - mv->dst_y));
                }
            }
            av_frame_unref(frame);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

static int open_codec_context(AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx, enum AVMediaType type)
{
    int ret;
    AVStream *st;
    AVCodecContext *dec_ctx = NULL;
    AVCodec *dec = NULL;
    AVDictionary *opts = NULL;

    ret = av_find_best_stream(fmt_ctx, type, -1, -1, &dec, 0);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find %s stream in input file '%s'\n",
                av_get_media_type_string(type), src_filename);
        return ret;
    } else {
        int stream_idx = ret;
        st = fmt_ctx->streams[stream_idx];

        dec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(dec);
        if (!dec_ctx) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate codec\n");
            return AVERROR(EINVAL);
        }

        ret = avcodec_parameters_to_context(dec_ctx, st->codecpar);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy codec parameters to codec context\n");
            return ret;
        }

        /* Init the video decoder */
        av_dict_set(&opts, "flags2", "+export_mvs", 0);
        if ((ret = avcodec_open2(dec_ctx, dec, &opts)) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s codec\n",
                    av_get_media_type_string(type));
            return ret;
        }

        video_stream_idx = stream_idx;
        video_stream = fmt_ctx->streams[video_stream_idx];
        video_dec_ctx = dec_ctx;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ret = 0;
    AVPacket pkt = { 0 };

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <video>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    src_filename = argv[1];

    if (avformat_open_input(&fmt_ctx, src_filename, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open source file %s\n", src_filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (avformat_find_stream_info(fmt_ctx, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find stream information\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    open_codec_context(fmt_ctx, AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

    av_dump_format(fmt_ctx, 0, src_filename, 0);

    if (!video_stream) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find video stream in the input, aborting\n");
        ret = 1;
        goto end;
    }

    frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!frame) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate frame\n");
        ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
        goto end;
    }

    printf("framenum,dx,dy\n");

    /* read frames from the file */
    while (av_read_frame(fmt_ctx, &pkt) >= 0) {
        if (pkt.stream_index == video_stream_idx)
            ret = decode_packet(&pkt);
        av_packet_unref(&pkt);
        if (ret < 0)
            break;
    }

    /* flush cached frames */
    decode_packet(NULL);

end:
    avcodec_free_context(&video_dec_ctx);
    avformat_close_input(&fmt_ctx);
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    return ret < 0;
}
```

Instead and outputting every frame, I only want to read one frame every 60 frames. The speed of the program is very important so I want to eliminate as much unnecessary code as possible. The problem is I'm having a hard time understanding how to advance the video stream without reading in new frames. I call `av_read_frame(fmt_ctx, &pkt)` to get packet info that is decoded by `decode_packet` and then goes on to read the next, but I can't find a way to only get packet info for one frame out of each 60.

Answer (score 0):

Use [av_seek_frame()](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.11/group__lavf__decoding.html#ga23f7619d8d4ea0857065d9979c75ac8) to read every 60th frame.